# Spring 4.0 REST call results in 406 error code

Tags: json, spring, rest

My REST calls to a simple controller i have setup always comes back with a 406 (not acceptable) response code.
My request header has Accept: 'application/json' and
I also have jackson libraries in my classpath

Spring version used 4.0.6 (I also tried 4.0.5).
App Server  Tomcat 8

My class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/menu")
public class TestController extends AbstractController {


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/config")
    public Map getConfig (final HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return new HashMap();
    }

}
```

I also tried changing my method annotation to:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/config", produces={"application/json"})
```

My Spring web context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>

    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/xml" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I also tried with a simple

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

tag and without the contentNegotiationManager bean. The application starts both ways and the method on the server is called, but i get the 406 response everytime.

Client request Headers:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8002
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: application/json,application/xml
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8002/myapp/login.rest
Cookie: JSESSIONID=431505385C0E8A5AAC878BA2B8AE1F92; 
Connection: keep-alive
```

Jackson libraries used and in my classpath:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also tried using the jackson 2.3.3 libraries.

Running a simple Spring boot example with an annotation only example works fine. I'm not sure what i am missing here.

Most of the other Spring 406 issues here on Stackoverflow seem to have to do with missing jackson libraries or incorrect request headers, both of which i have.

I think my spring web context file is missing something. But i was under the impression that Spring should handle converting my response to JSON automatically.
Any ideas on what i am missing here?

In all my attempts, the server code is called but the response is 406 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This is embarrassing. The issue turned out to be that i had another application-context.xml file (misspelled  by one letter). The misspelled application-context file was the one being used and had configuration for spring 3.2.4.(The version of spring prior to our upgrade)

I kept updating and changing the application-context.xml file that was not being referred to in web.xml and so was just not used by spring.

Removed the duplicate file with the old config, and updated web.xml to reference the right file and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Just curious why you had not declared `@ResponseBody` together in your return Object

Comment: @manuel-jordan, As of spring 4.0, with the Restcontoller annotation the Responsebody is not required

Comment: Agree, sorry I have read not correctly, I read by mistake only `@Controller`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call this URL directly from browser, it will throw 406 error. However, if you're doing so through an AJAX request, and still it throws 406 error, you may try the following workaround [Works in my case] :

**1. Edit your content negotiation manager to include the following property**

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

  <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
  </bean>

  <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>
```

**2. Change your @RequestMapping to the following**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "yourURL", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json", headers = "Accept=*/*")
```

This worked in my case. Hope that it works for you too.. !!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but it doesn't work for me, and I'm making an AJAX call from my app.

Comment: Make sure that you don't test this URL directly from the browser. Make the call through an ajax request.